# How to make Bokeh Datatable fit responsively

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to make my datatable fit full width but I'm struggling to achieve this.

I would like to avoid giving a fixed with to the table.

This is the code for the table. I'm using the get_table function to generate it and the componnets_web function to get the div and script tags. then display it somewhere else using bokeh.layouts.layout.

```
def get_table(self):
    '''
    creates a bokeh table widget from provided dataframe.
    :param dataframe: A pandas dataframe
    :return: data_table: A Bokeh widget
    '''

    from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn

    source = ColumnDataSource(self.dataframe)
    columns = [TableColumn(field=f, title=f) for f in self.headers]
    data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns)

    return data_table

def components_web(plot):
    '''
    Generates html components for web display.
    :param plot: A bokeh plot
    :return: script: A html <script> tag with render javascript, div a <div> tag with html to display a bokeh plot,
    resources: A <script> tag with javascript to render bokeh plots.
    '''

    from bokeh.resources import CDN
    from bokeh.embed import components

    script, div = components(plot, CDN)

    return script, div
```

Then to actually display it and get a layout:

```
    table = br.get_table()
    script, div = br.components_web(layout([table], sizing_mode='stretch_both'))
    resource = br.bokeh_web_resources()
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had luck doing this by ensuring that all components held the table were also set to `sizing_mode = "stretch_both"`.

For example, in your code you specify `sizing_mode = "stretch_both"` for the `layout` but not for the `table` itself. I would try starting with that. You may need to specify the sizing mode for additional components if you have more nesting that is not quite obvious in the code snippet. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to overwrite the Bokeh CSS styles by inspecting the Bokeh table css classes in the browser and create your own ones with different width attribute than put it in an external style.css file and refer to it by adding `css_classes = ["my_class"]` attribute to the TableColumn and DataTable. This can be however pretty difficult as there are many classes and you don't know exactly which ones to target.

Instead I suggest the following solution where you can allow the user to set a custom table width with the slider. The same idea can be also applied to the table height.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider, DataTable, TableColumn

def get_square(n):
    return dict(x = list(range(n)), y = [x ** 2 for x in range(n)])

source = ColumnDataSource(get_square(15))
columns = [TableColumn(field = "x", title = "x"), TableColumn(field = "y", title = "x**2")]

table = DataTable(source = source, columns = columns, width = 300, css_classes = ['my_class'])
slider = Slider(start = 1, end = 200, value = 15, step = 1, title = "i", width = 300)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    table.source.data = get_square(slider.value)
    table.width = 300 + slider.value * 25
    table.update()

slider.on_change('value', update_data)

layout = widgetbox(slider, table)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```